# Capturing the Enter key when editing a GridView textbox

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView defined like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" ruant="server">
    <asp:BoundField DataField="myField" />
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" />
</asp:GridView>
```

After I put a row into edit mode with the Edit button, how do I capture the Enter key and trigger the resulting Update on the row? Right now if I hit enter, the page reloads, what was entered into the TextBox is lost, and the row stays in edit mode. I know how to [disable the enter key entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152099/i-want-to-prevent-aspnet-gridview-from-reacting-to-the-enter-button) on the form (the current workaround), but I'd like to have it fire the Update command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, using the knowledge from the question you linked, it's simple:

```
string js = "if (event.keyCode == 13) this.form.submit();"
myGridView.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", js);
```

As we found out in the comments, this introduces a small problem. The `GridView_RowUpdating` server event does not fire anymore, but the question author relies on it.

In short - the server event model relies on the form field `__EVENTTARGET` to be set. This form field is not sent when just calling the `form.submit()`. A solution would be to "click" the relevant button with JavaScript.

```
string js = "if ((event.which && event.which == 13) || " 
            + "(event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13)) "
            + "{document.myForm.Update.click();return false;} "
            + "else return true;";
myGridView.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", js);
```

See ["Using the enter key to submit a form"](http://www.allasp.net/enterkey.aspx) on AllAsp.net, which covers the issue in more detail.

Comment: No, that just mimics the behavior as if there were no "onkeydown" event.

Comment: Can you explain? For me this submits the form.

Comment: (Please check that the "submit" button is not named "submit", as this overrides the form.submit() function.)

Comment: No, in this case the button is named Update. Submitting the form does not trigger the GridView_RowUpdating event, where the underlying update happens.

Comment: Yes, but by not triggering the event to write the new value, it's no different than refreshing the page.

Comment: Thinking about it, I have a suspicion. The event cannot fire when the event source is unclear to the server (e.g. "which button was klicked?"). But in this case no button is clicked. I changed my code sample a bit. Please confirm if it works!

Comment: I've done something similar before, and it may be the only way around this. Thanks for hashing this out with me.

Answer (score 0):

Set "UseSubmitBehavior" property of buttons on the page to "False" (default is True)
solves the submit issue in several comments.