# capture the enter on gridview inline editing and make update

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

When I use the inline editing on a GridView, and start edit a line, when I press enter on any text editor, is not Update the line, but is cancel it, close the Update and return back.

How can I prevent that, and when I press enter to submit the updates on the line using jQuery.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLista" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" >

        <-- rest of BoundField with editors or other data -->
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />         
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we do not use UpdatePanel, then we capture the editors on the GridView, and on press enter, we locate the Update Button on the same line and submit it like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {         
    // capture the open editors inside the GridView (if any)
    jQuery('#<%= gvLista.ClientID %> :input[type=text]').keydown(function (e) 
    {
        // on keydown if is press the enter
        if (e.keyCode == 13) 
        {
            // not let him submit the form on any other button
            e.preventDefault();
            // but find on the same line, the Update Button, and submit that one
            jQuery(this).parents("tr").find("input[value=Update]").click();
        }
    });
});
```

If we use UpdatePanel the idea is the same, but we must initialize that using the UpdatePanel functions, every time UpdatePanel Updates their content.

Relative questions and links:
[Capturing the Enter key when editing a GridView textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258661/capturing-the-enter-key-when-editing-a-gridview-textbox)
[Handling the Enter key pressed in a GridView's row edit mode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38579/Handling-the-Enter-key-pressed-in-a-GridView-s-row)