# Why does Enter or Tab key cause a validation on a TextBox?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Why does this markup ...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExValidatorTextBox1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
                                Text="Invalid date format." 
                                ValidationExpression="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

... throw a validation error when I enter some nonsense in the TextBox like "a" and hit only the Enter or Tab key? I' like to have the validation not before I click on a submit button.

(I'm working with VS2008 SP1, .NET 3.5 SP1, if that matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question (Why does Enter or Tab key cause a validation on a TextBox?), when you press Enter, the [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx) will cause the form to post back. Pressing enter is akin to clicking on the submit button.

If you want to disable the postback on enter, there are [several solutions suggested here](http://forums.asp.net/t/914295.aspx), also [see here](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/05/28/prevent-enter-key-using-asp-net-ajax.aspx) and [here for a JQuery based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152099/i-want-to-prevent-asp-net-gridview-from-reacting-to-the-enter-button).

Comment: But there is absolutely no button on the page (not yet). The page is a simple test page containing only the TextBox and the Validator.

Comment: Yes, but the form will submit on enter.

Comment: @Slauma- I've edited my answer- have a look at some of the suggestions in the link I sent out.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I wasn't aware that simply hitting the ENTER key causes a postback of a form.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [EnableClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) property to false. This will completely prevent validation on the client side. Then on the server side, be sure to check the Page.IsValid property before proceeding.

Comment: I've just tried it to disable client script in the validator. Now the validation does not fire when I hit TAB but still when I hit ENTER.

Comment: Well, I think I understand: On ENTER a postback occurs and the validation happens on server side - in contrast to hitting the TAB key.