# Automatic addition of row GridView in ASP.NET upon pressing ENTER key during Edit

Tags: asp.net, gridview

After entering updated values in the text box (say Unit Price), and if I press ENTER key, I see a new ROW automatically added at the last with values 0 or empty in the cells.

How to prevent this automatic addition of a row happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have look for other question that may help you. 
They suggest to do that :

```
myGridView.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.keyCode==13)return false;");
```

I leave you the old question link : 
[I want to prevent ASP.NET GridView from reacting to the enter button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152099/i-want-to-prevent-asp-net-gridview-from-reacting-to-the-enter-button)